# swap array elements in nested loop with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

I wanna my divs to be sorted but in this code it only goes through for loop once. How can i make this to end both loops and my divs sorted?

```js
var arr = [4, 7, 1, 9, 8, 13, 6, 11];

function showarray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var divSort = document.createElement("div");
    divSort.style.width = 30 + "px";
    divSort.style.height = 30 + "px";
    divSort.style.background = "yellow";
    divSort.style.display = "inline-block";
    divSort.style.margin = "10px";
    divSort.id = arr[i];
    divSort.innerHTML = arr[i];
    document.body.appendChild(divSort);
  }
}
showarray();

function func() {
  for (var j = (arr.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= j; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
        doSetTimeout(i, j);
      };
    };
  }

  function doSetTimeout(i, j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + arr[i]).insertBefore("#" + arr[i - 1]);
    }, j * i * 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
```

Comment: So you want to perform animated sorting or just sort the `div` elements? What's the point of your delay

Comment: @RamisWachtler  animated sorting. I want to use delay to show how algorithm works

Comment: Please provide proper explanation of expected behavior. Code that doesn't work isn't a substitute for explaining what you want that code to do

Comment: @charlietfl code works but it only performs 2nd loop not the first one. But i need both loop in order to make my divs sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only iterating one time because you aren't changing the array indexes, you are just updating the div positions, so everytime you iterate the array, it hasn't changed (just your divs). So you are always iterating the same array, doing the same changes over and over again. You need to change the array values and also change the div positions:

```js
var arr = [4, 7, 1, 9, 8, 13, 6, 11];
var counter = 0;

function showarray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var divSort = document.createElement("div");
    divSort.style.width = 30 + "px";
    divSort.style.height = 30 + "px";
    divSort.style.background = "yellow";
    divSort.style.display = "inline-block";
    divSort.style.margin = "10px";
    divSort.id = arr[i];
    divSort.innerHTML = arr[i];
    document.body.appendChild(divSort);
  }
}
showarray();

function func() {
  for (var j = arr.length; j > 0; j--) {
    for (var i = 0; i < (arr.length-1); i++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        swap(i+1, i);
      }
    };
  }

  function swap(smaller, bigger) {
    var tmpBigger = arr[bigger];
    var tmpSmaller = arr[smaller];
    arr[bigger] = tmpSmaller
    arr[smaller] = tmpBigger;
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + tmpSmaller).insertBefore("#" + tmpBigger);
    }, ++counter * 500);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
```

Comment: I changed your sorting algorithm a bit, so i'd suggest checking that (yours might be a different one) but the swap function should be ok, as long as you feed it the smaller value index first and the bigger value index as second argument.